# fulltext search pdo with array elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a problem with a fulltext search query which works before I updated phpmyadmin I think. Lets start:

I get from the first select query a array named `$keywordse` with `$keywordse = $resi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` If I run `var_dump($keywordse);` I get the following output:

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { 
["keyword1"]=> string(4) "test" 
["keyword2"]=> string(5) "asdfr" 
["keyword3"]=> string(4) "roof" 
 } }
```

After the first query I added `$keywordsonetoeight = implode(',', $keywordse);` to convert the array for the second query. At this line I get

> Notice: Array to string conversion

**the second query:**

```
                    try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loginsystem",$user,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // 
                         $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, autor, title, text, time 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, text) AGAINST ('$keywordsonetoeight')
ORDER BY id DESC"; 
  if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
      // then after fetchColumn
     $result = $res->fetchAll();     
   }
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        //echo $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Is there anything wrong with the second query or with the the variable `$keywordsonetoeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your conversion is wrong, you must convert the first entry of $keywordse to get the keywords as a string.

```
$keywordsonetoeight = implode(',', $keywordse[0]);
```

I am not sure if comma seperated is correct maybe you just need spaces in the query, but I cannot check this right now.